# Not able to access array named routes and check if it's null or not

Tags: android, json, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to show Toast containing message "error" when a user tries to find direction between places of 2 different countries like directions from Taj Mahal to Paris. I have targeted routes array for this to check if it's null or not and if it's null then Toast should appear else direction will be shown. Below is my code:

```
 public String[] parseDirections(String jsonData){
            JSONArray jsonArray=null;
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            JSONArray jsonArray1;
    try {
        if(jsonData!=null) {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);

            jsonArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            if (jsonArray1 != null && jsonArray1.length() > 0) {
                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("steps");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mcontext, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(jsonObject.getString("routes"), "error in code");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    catch(NullPointerException e){
        Toast.makeText(mcontext,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return getPaths(jsonArray);
}
```

and below is the jsonData output for invalid search.

```
jsonData : {   "geocoded_waypoints" : [ {}, {} ],   "routes" : [],   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"}
```

My problem is that I am not able to access routes array and check if it's empty or not and not getting the toast as well.

**GetDirectionsData.java**

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            try {
        String[] directionsList;

        DataParser parser = new DataParser();
        directionsList = parser.parseDirections(s);

            HashMap<String, String> directionsList1;
            directionsList1 = parser.parseDuration(s);

            duration = directionsList1.get("duration");
            distance = directionsList1.get("distance");

            mMap.clear();
            displayDirection(directionsList);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**MapsSearch.java**

```
case R.id.B_to: //on click of this button, process starts
                try{
                Object dataTransfer1[]=new Object[3];

                String url=getDirectionsUrl();
                GetDirectionsData getDirectionsData=new GetDirectionsData();
                dataTransfer1[0]=mMap;
                dataTransfer1[1]=url;
                dataTransfer1[2]=new LatLng(end_latitude,end_longitude);

                Log.d(TAG, "datatransfered:" + dataTransfer1 + " error in code");

                getDirectionsData.execute(dataTransfer1);

            }

            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
```

**getDirectionsUrl() in MapsSearch.java**

```
 private String getDirectionsUrl(){
        StringBuilder googleDirectionsUrl=null;
        try {
            googleDirectionsUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?");
            googleDirectionsUrl.append("origin=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
            googleDirectionsUrl.append("&destination=" + end_latitude + "," + end_longitude);
            googleDirectionsUrl.append(("&alternatives=true"));
            googleDirectionsUrl.append("&key=" + "hereIsMyKey");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return googleDirectionsUrl.toString();
    }
```

Comment: just use AsyncTask to fetching the routes and after completion of that task check whether there's any route available or not

Answer (score 0):

This will surely return a output, even if json parsing throws exception.

```
public static String[] parseDirections(String jsonData) {
    JSONArray output = null;
    JSONObject data;
    try {
        if (jsonData != null) {
            data = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            if (data.has("routes")) {
                JSONArray routes = data.getJSONArray("routes");
                if (routes.length() > 0) {
                    JSONObject route0 = routes.getJSONObject(0);
                    if (route0.has("legs")) {
                        JSONArray legs = route0.getJSONArray("legs");
                        if (legs.length() > 0) {
                            JSONObject legs0 = legs.getJSONObject(0);
                            if (legs0.has("steps")) {
                                output = legs0.getJSONArray("steps");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (data.has("status")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "" + data.getString("status") + " error in code");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (output == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return getPaths(output);
    }
}
```

In your case may be json parsing exception is thrown.

```
private void fetchDirectionData() {
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=19.122425,72.911002&destination=24.882134,55.305983&alternatives=true&key=AIzaSyDWa-XeSJTdm6kfsmzPoalpC6NJjd0WeFk";
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, data,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //here you will get the response
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }
    );
    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            10000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: I replaced my part of code with yours and as I have shown jsonData output in my post, length of routes array is 0 when asking for invalid route but it's still executing  if (routes.length() > 0) statement rather than executing else {if (data.has("status")) ..}  one. I don't know what's the reason.

Comment: D/TestActivity: parseDirections: 
03-06 17:27:32.916 4925-4925/com.abacus.appliedsingularity D/TestActivity: ZERO_RESULTS error in code

Tested it's working at my end @Kinjal

Comment: It's not working for me. It always runs  if (routes.length() > 0) and I don't know why is this happening. Even in my code, it used to execute if (jsonArray1 != null && jsonArray1.length() > 0) always and that's what my problem is! Anyways, thanks. :)

Comment: Please check the data u are passing to method again. Put logs in method where needed

Comment: I am passing these 3 things. Object dataTransfer1[]=new Object[3];

                    String url=getDirectionsUrl();
                    GetDirectionsData getDirectionsData=new GetDirectionsData();
                    dataTransfer1[0]=mMap;
                    dataTransfer1[1]=url;
                    dataTransfer1[2]=new LatLng(end_latitude,end_longitude);

                    Log.d(TAG, "datatransfered:" + dataTransfer1 + " error in code");

                    getDirectionsData.execute(dataTransfer1);

Comment: which then goes here..  protected void onPostExecute(String s) { String[] directionsList;

            DataParser parser = new DataParser(context);
            directionsList = parser.parseDirections(s); .....} and then to parseDirections method shown in the post.

Comment: @Kinjal add this to the same question so that i can check where you are going wrong.

Comment: Hi Kinjal, why don't you try https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html for fetching data from server. Also print logs on post execute for printing String s.

Comment: also pdated answer for fetching data